# Install Windows 7 on a Netbook

Tags: windows-7, netbook

I have a netbook, namely: Compaq CQ10-525DX.

The main specs are:
Intel Atom N455 1.66GHz processor with the Intel GMA 3150 chip graphics,
1GB of DDR2 RAM, 
a 160GB hard drive.

I want to install Windows 7 and I'm thinking of the Home Basic edition. Will it matter if I go higher such as Professional or Ultimate? Also should I install 64-bit of 32-bit. I'm thinking of going with the 32-bit Windows 7 Home Basic edition. I just wanted to make sure that my hardware will be able to take it.

Comment: First ask yourself what will you use the netbook for? Also check out - http://windows.microsoft.com/upgradeadvisor

Comment: @Mayank mainly college stuff such as word processing and browsing stuff on the internet. I don't think I'll be photo editing or video processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Upgrade Advisor](http://windows.microsoft.com/upgradeadvisor) that I ran on my work PC -

For 64-bit Windows 7:

[image]

For 32-bit Windows 7:

[image]

So as you can see the difference if for RAM and disk space required.

I would still advise you to go for the version which satisfies your need and not to waste unnecessary $$.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be a problem upgrading this to Windows 7 32-bit Home Basic Edition. 
If you've thought about how you're going to use it, and checked the link Mayank provided.

Answer (score 1):

i've run windows 7 professional on pretty much lower specs and that, and it ran pretty well. The main possible bottleneck i see is the ram - 1gb is enough, but its the bare minimum i recommend with with windows 7- 2gb is a little bit more comfortable.

Other than that, any version should probably run fine on that system.

Most netbooks come with windows 7 starter, which is good enough for basic things. I've not seem home basic out here since its for developing countries only, but Unless you need some feature specific to the higher versions (I run professional for RDP and xp mode support for example), it would make sense to get a home version.Wikipedia has a [table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions#Sub-editions) talking about the different featuresets of windows 7 varients.

Comment: I´d agree with you. I upgraded my EeePC 1000H netbook to 2 GB RAM and Win7 home runs fine on it.